# Why is my triangle's area/perimeter 0?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write a code for where the user inputs two legs of a triangle and the program will calculate the hypotenuse, area, and perimeter. However, all my outputs are 0.
Here is the code:

```java
package practice;

public class RightTri {

    double leg1;
    double leg2;
    double hypotenuse;
    double Area;
    double Perimeter;

    public RightTri() {
        leg1=0;
        leg2=0;
        hypotenuse=0;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double Area= leg1*leg2*0.5;
        return Area;
    }

    public double getHypotenuse() {
        double Hypotenuse=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(leg1, 2.0)+Math.pow(leg2, 2.0));
        return Hypotenuse;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        double Perimeter= leg1+leg2+hypotenuse;
        return Perimeter;
    }
}
```

```java
package practice;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RightTriTest {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        RightTri Test=new RightTri();
        String a= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 1?");
        Double leg1=Double.parseDouble(a);
        String b= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 2?");
        Double leg2=Double.parseDouble(b);
        System.out.println("The hypotenuse is " +Test.getHypotenuse());
        System.out.println("The area is " +Test.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is " +Test.getPerimeter());   
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about variable scopes ...

Comment: In my opinion this question does not deserve all the downvotes: yes, to those with more experience, it is obvious but that does not invalidate the question. General Relativity is also obvious to folk who have spent their lifetime studying it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public RightTri()
{
    leg1=0;
    leg2=0;
    hypotenuse=0;
}
```

All you values are 0 in your no-arg constructor

You should use a constructor like this

```
public RightTri(double leg1, double leg2)
{
   this.leg1 = leg1;
   this.leg2 = leg2;
}
```

Then in the main do something like this

```
String a= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 1?");
Double leg1=Double.parseDouble(a);
String b= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 2?");
Double leg2=Double.parseDouble(b);

RightTri Test = new RightTri(leg1, leg2);

System.out.println("The hypotenuse is " +Test.getHypotenuse());
System.out.println("The area is " +Test.getArea());
System.out.println("The perimeter is " +Test.getPerimeter());
```

Comment: Thank you guys! The only problem now is that the area and permimeter only uses leg1 and leg2 in the calculations, and not factor in the hypotenuse. Help?

Comment: because you only calculate the hypotenuse in `getHypotenuse()`, not in `getPerimeter()`.

Comment: Use `double Perimeter= leg1+leg2+ getHypotenuse();` in your `getPerimeter()`

Comment: Area doesn't need hypotenuse. leg1*leg2*0.5 is correct calculation

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your triangle's values to be `0`:

```
public RightTri()
{
    leg1=0;
    leg2=0;
    hypotenuse=0;
}
```

You never change any of them, so when you call `getArea()`...

```
public double getArea()
{
    double Area= leg1*leg2*0.5;
    return Area;
}
```

...you get `0` because `0 * 0 * 0.5` is zero.

You seem to have confused local variables in the `main` method with the ones in your triangle object. Try making a more sensible constructor instead:

```
public RightTri(double leg1, double leg2) {
    this.leg1 = leg1;
    this.leg2 = leg2;
}
```

And calling it from `main`, for example like this:

```
RightTri a = new RightTri(4, 6);
System.out.println(a.getArea());
```

Alternatively, since the fields are not `private`, you could access them directly from `main`:

```
Test.leg1 = 4.5;
```

But this isn't very idiomatic to Java, so I recommend using the constructor.

Comment: You might also want to pre-compute the hypotenuse in the constructor too.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the values that you obtain for leg1 and leg2 are not being assigned in your "Test" object. I recommend you to create a couple setters in your class RightTri:

```
public void setLeg1(Double leg1){
    this.leg1 = leg1;
}

public void setLeg2(Double leg2){
    this.leg2 = leg2;
}
```

And then assign the values from RightTriTest:

```
 public static void main (String args[]) {
    RightTri Test=new RightTri();
    String a= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 1?");
    Double leg1=Double.parseDouble(a);
    Test.setLeg1(leg1);
    String b= JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Leg 2?");
    Double leg2=Double.parseDouble(b);
    Test.setLeg2(leg2);
    System.out.println("The hypotenuse is " +Test.getHypotenuse());
    System.out.println("The area is " +Test.getArea());
    System.out.println("The perimeter is " +Test.getPerimeter());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said it yourself: constructing a zero triangle is meaningless. Why not drop your default (*i.e.* no argument) constructor altogether?

Supply this instead:

```
public RightTri(double leg1, double leg2)
{
   this.leg1 = leg1;
   this.leg2 = leg2;
   this.hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(leg1 * leg1 + leg2 * leg2);
}
```

Notice that I've bought the hypotenuse calculation inside the constructor. You might even want to bring the setting of `Area` and `Perimeter` inside it too: then you can guarantee that the object is in a well-formed state on construction at the expense of virtually negligible overhead. Of course, you'll need to adjust your various `get...` functions.

I've also dropped the `pow` functions. The way you have them with `2.0` as the argument will invoke a slow computation: it's much quicker for powers of 2 to multiply the numbers yourself.